# PHP insert input data array using foreach

Tags: php

I cannot figure this out. I am trying to match keys and values and insert them into the db and I cannot get the room_id value.

Here is my `var_dump`:

```
array(6) { 
    ["checkbox_1"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["footage"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "55" }
    ["room_id"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" }  
    ["company_id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["client_id"]=> string(3) "709" 
    ["submit_form"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

Here is my code:

```
if (is_array($_POST)) {

foreach($_POST['footage'] as $key => $val){

if($val != ''){

$room_id = $_POST['room_id'][$key]; //fixed

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO home_details 
    (room_id, footage) 

VALUES ('".$room_id."',
    '".$val."'
    )");

    echo "<br>Added.";

               }
      }
}
```

$val = 55 but $room_id is empty.

Comment: Key of array **never** can be an array

Comment: Change this: $room_id = $key['room_id']; by this: $room_id = $key;

Comment: @u_mulder so how do I get room_id to equal 6 and insert it?

Comment: @ADASein that just gives me the key which is 0

Comment: From the provided structure - `$room_id` is `$_POST['room_id'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at your `print_r`:

```
$id = $_POST['room_id'][0];
```

Altho something is wrong with your HTML form

Answer (score 0):

Added [$key] to the end of POST_['room_id']. Thanks. Works great

```
if (is_array($_POST)) {

foreach($_POST['footage'] as $key => $val){

if($val != ''){

$room_id = $_POST['room_id'][$key]; //fixed

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO home_details 
(room_id, footage) 

VALUES ('".$room_id."',
'".$val."'
)");

echo "<br>Added.";

           }
     }
}
```